# LinearLayout cause "requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout"

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

Currently I have a code where I have a recyclerview and a cardview. The recyclerview adapter will display the a list cards and for individual card, the data will be different. The problem comes here. Once I run my application, I will received `requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout` warning and this warning will disrupt my application flow because I can't launch any activity after the following warnings appear. Below is my logcat and xml. Thank you.

`Logcat`

```
05-24 16:21:40.065 30277-30277/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{d42d2b7 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00ce app:id/card_location_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-24 16:21:40.065 30277-30277/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{231aa24 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00d1 app:id/card_jobtype_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-24 16:21:40.065 30277-30277/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{cd4998d V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00ce app:id/card_location_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-24 16:21:40.065 30277-30277/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{d5c8742 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00d1 app:id/card_jobtype_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-24 16:21:40.065 30277-30277/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{a7e353 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00ce app:id/card_location_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-24 16:21:40.065 30277-30277/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{3f14490 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00d1 app:id/card_jobtype_container} during layout: running second layout pass
```

After looking further into the code, I discovered that it's my LinearLayout (card_location_container & card_jobtype_container)card view generating the problem. I tried changing to `RelativeLayout` but the whole `CardView` disappear instead.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="25dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offer_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_card_title"
            style="@style/ShadowText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Job Title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_card_company_name"
            style="@style/ShadowText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="Company Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/job_card_company_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/card_location_container"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/job_card_image_location"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_on_black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_card_company_location"
                style="@style/ShadowText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Company Location"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_jobtype_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_location_container"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/job_card_image_job_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_work" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_card_job_type"
                style="@style/ShadowText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Job Type"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_image"
            style="@style/ShadowText"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
            android:src="@drawable/job_card_apply"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/job_card_reject"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The layout originally look like:
[image]

If I change it to RelativeLayout
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to include the name of your employer?

Comment: Yes. It's okay.

Comment: try removing `right_image` and `left_image` from bottom and declare jst below `job_card_title`

Comment: also everywhere in the layout for `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` use `@id` instead of `@+id`

Comment: can you paste the Java code where you are inflating the card views?

Comment: Where do u call `setText` on the `@id/job_card_company_location` TextView ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this layout and arrange as you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="25dp"
            android:textAlignment="center">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/offer_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_card_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Job Title"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_card_company_name"
                style="@style/ShadowText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Company Name"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_location_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/job_card_image_location"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/job_card_company_location"
                    style="@style/ShadowText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Company Location"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_jobtype_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/job_card_image_job_type"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_work" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/job_card_job_type"
                    style="@style/ShadowText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Job Type"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/left_image"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/job_card_reject"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/right_image"
                    style="@style/ShadowText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/job_card_apply"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />




            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white">

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The warning still pop up

Comment: Could you show me the activity code where you are using this cardview and recyclerview

Comment: I'm not using a recyclerview, but instead I use an external library SwipeDeck to make tinder like card view.

Comment: I think its a bug inside the SwipeDeck library code. I think the issue arises when we initialize the adapter a requestLayout() function is called inside the library class. Im not sure but may be this warning occurs because when we set the adapter to SwipeDeck object request layout is called again and may be the are getting clashed into each other.  There are similar errors in AndroidSwipeLayout by daimajia.  Im sorry I couldnt help